# Why am I getting "Call to undefined function findOne()" here?

Tags: php, mongodb

I've got a little PHP script that has the following code in it:

```
$m = new MongoClient(Settings::$db);
$db = $m->db;

// get the 'customers' collection
$customers = $db->customers;

// determine if this customer already exists
$c = $customers.findOne(array('email' => $email)); <--- throws
if (is_null($c)) {
    $customers.insert(array(
        'email' => $email,
        'firstname' => $firstName,
        'lastname' => $lastName
    ));
}

// get the 'payments' collection
$payments = $db->payments;

// add a record
$payments->insert(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'firstname' => $firstName,
    'lastname' => $lastName,
    'amount' => $price,
    'token' => $token
));
```

but it's throwing the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function findOne() in ...

Now, I've downloaded and copied into the `ext` directory the `php_mongo.dll` file. Further, I've added this line to the `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_mongo.dll
```

and I've since rebooted the server numerous times.

**It really feels to me like this `findOne` method isn't available because the `php_mongo` extension isn't loaded.** But on the other hand, it's not throwing when creating the `MongoClient`, nor is it throwing when grabbing the database and the collection.

What's going on here?

Comment: Myabe it's a typo here, but `$customers.findOne(..)` shouldn't be `$customers->findOne(..)` ? It's php afterall

Comment: @DamienPirsy, add that as the answer my friend! Wow, I'm a bit embarrassed. It happens to us all I guess. :D

Comment: Yeah, especially working with different languages, and different property/method access syntaxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you likely used another language's method access syntax by mistake:

This

```
$c = $customers.findOne(array('email' => $email));
```

is alas PHP so you need the object operator not the dot:

```
$c = $customers->findOne(array('email' => $email));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think dot is the mistake.try

```
$c = $customers->findOne(array('email' => $email));
```